# Bootstrap 2 Column with containers inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm making a layout in bootstrap and I'am having a hard time figuring out how to place a "container" class inside a full width "row" class to have a perfect alignment on the content.

attached an image for reference and part of my code.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #ebebeb;">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #fafbc6;">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @il_raffa - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

place bootstap class "container" inside "container-fluid"  class.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #ebebeb;">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #fafbc6;">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```